# Message running python2.7 from Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda

When I run python I get the following messages:

```
/Users/eduardomartinez/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

This happens *every time* and takes 10 secs or more.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your font cache is corrupt. According to the linked `matplotlib` issues page, you can try the following from the terminal.

First try:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/matplotlib
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
```

---

If the first doesn't work, then remove the fontList.cache

```
rm -rf ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache
```

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5836

Comment: Removing the fontList.cache fixed it. Thanks